# passing data from unmanaged code (C) to managed code (C#)

Tags: c#, c

I have an application that is written in `C#` and uses a DLL written in `C`.
Through some delegate (function pointer), I have managed to invoke a `C` function. This function is expected to do a lot of processing on some data and then return the processed binary data back to `C#` code along with size of data.

The prototype for managed `c#` function is:

`private unsafe delegate void MyCallback (IntPtr cs_buf, Int32 cs_size);`

And I am calling this from my `C code` as:

```
void* c_buf = NULL;
int c_size = 0;

.... some processing here to fill buf and size......

MyCallback (c_buf, c_size);
```

In the managed `C#` code, I need to call a function from `MyCallback` that has the prototype:

`void foo (byte[] cs_buf, int cs_size)`

Now there is no problem with the `cs_size` value, but what is the correct way to use/pass the binary buffer from C code to C# code so that it can be used as a `byte[]` in C# code.

If what I am doing is the correct way, what should be the recommended way of converting the received `IntPtr cs_buf` to `byte[]`?

Thanks,
Vikram

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`Marshal.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146631.aspx)

> `Marshal.Copy Method (IntPtr, Byte[], Int32, Int32)`
>
> Copies data from an unmanaged memory pointer to a managed 8-bit
>   unsigned integer array.

Assuming that `cs_size` is the size in bytes :

```
var array = new byte[cs_size];
Marshal.Copy(pointer, array, 0, cs_size);
foo(array, cs_size);
```

By the way int this case `foo()` don't need to take a `cs_size` parameter as it could use the `.Length` property of the array instead.

---

Also with this, as the C# code copy the array, you could `free()` the buffer from the C code just after calling the callback.

Otherwise you will need either to export a `mylib_free()` method from C or use a known memory allocator (NOT `malloc`) like [`LocalAlloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366723.aspx) (From C) and [`Marshal.FreeHGlobal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freehglobal.aspx) (From C#) under Windows.

Comment: If you don't have any managed C++ code in your project, and it's just this one call, this is the best solution.

Comment: +1. That worked. Thanks :). However, I was just thinking, doesn't this introduces an extra copy overhead?

Comment: It does, but it is still the best solution if you don't have any managed C++ and you don't have a lot of such calls and the performance isn't very important.  My answer can be used to avoid the extra copy, but you have to make a C++ project (which can compile to a dot-net assembly).

Comment: It does, you could also use either unsafe code or Marshal.Copy + one of the BitConverter methods to access the values directly without copying.

Comment: What you can't do (even in managed c++) is to convert a pointer to a managed (byte[]) array without copying. But you could implement an IList<T> or IEnumerable<T> that wrap a pointer to an unmanaged array and use that in most places. So you can't do without a copy in your case, not without changing the prototype of `foo` to take something else than an array as parameter.

Answer (score 4):

This is what Microsoft made C++/CLI for (also known as Managed C++).  You could write a function like this:

```
void call_foo(array<Byte>^ bytes)
{
    pin_ptr<Byte> ptrBuffer = &bytes[bytes->GetLowerBound(0)];
    foo(ptrBuffer, bytes->Length);
}
```

This would take a C# array of bytes, pin its memory, and then pass it as a C style array of bytes to foo, with its length.  There is no need for cleanup or to free anything.  The pinned pointer will get auto-unpinned when it goes out of scope at the end of call_foo.  Clean and simple.