# Pass unmanaged data around in managed code?

Tags: c++-cli, windows-forms-designer, arrayfire

I'm building a Windows Form application that controls 3D volume rendering using an ArrayFire  `array` object. The `array` is unmanaged. In the form constructor, I load and render the volume.

I have a `Trackbar` that controls the opacity of the volume and a corresponding scroll event handler. However, I can't figure out how to pass the volume `array` to the `Trackbar` scroll event handler so I can re-render the volume.

I can't make the volume `array` an attribute of the Form because, apparently, managed classes cannot have unmanaged attributes.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763703/passing-data-from-unmanaged-code-c-to-managed-code-c

Comment: Thanks Pavan. See you on the AF forums ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A managed class cannot have a field that is an unmanaged type, but it can have a field that is a *pointer* to an unmanaged type. Stick a `*` at the end of your unmanaged type, and you should be able to pass it to whatever methods you want, and store it wherever you want.